# Is it possible to catch cmd.exe output format (and maybe colors) in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

If I run `ng build -environment=localprod --base-href /Angular5Starter/` in command prompt I receive the following output:

[image: Command prompt output]

However, if I run the same command from Powershell:

```
$ngBuildCommand = "ng build -environment=$($environment) --base-href /$($webSiteName)/"
Write-Host "Ng build command: ", $ngBuildCommand
cmd /c $ngBuildCommand
```

I receive a quite messed up output:

[image: Powershell output]

---

I have followed the suggestions from the comments and ran the command properly:

```
$ngExe = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng.cmd"
& $ngExe build -environment="$environment" --base-href /$webSiteName/
```

However, the output text format is the same.

**Question:** Is it possible to catch cmd.exe output format (and maybe colors) in Powershell?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using powershell to run cmd.exe? Just run the command directly. One way `& $ngBuildCommand`

Comment: @Appleoddity - This is part of a larger script with deals with starting and stopping IIS application pools and Powershell is helping a lot in this area.

Comment: Again, the purpose of powershell is to completely replace cmd.exe. There is nothing in cmd.exe you can’t do in powershell. You shouldn’t be running cmd.exe to simply execute an .exe file which is what this line of code does. This is not good scripting.

Comment: @Appleoddity - I receive the following error: `The term 'ng build -environment=localprod --base-href /Angular5Starter/' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or op
erable program.`

Comment: Give the path to the executable and include the .exe on the end.

Comment: @EBGreen - I have fixed the script and it looks much better. Thanks.

Comment: What you’re looking at are ANSI escape codes for color. It’s not supported in powershell. But I found at least one script for converting the codes to color parameters for write-host. You’ll have to dig around.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178582/8928481

Comment: @Biswapriyo - that's a good lead. I have tried it and it works pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized that my post is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What I really want is readable output, not colored one.

I have tried `Biswapriyo`'s solution and it works well except for two things:

- colors are changed (not a big deal)
- some strings (near the { }) are missing

What seems to solve the problem is to actually strip the colors from angular-cli's output, as indicated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6478):

```
$ngExe = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng.cmd" 
$executionRes = & $ngExe build -environment="$environment" --base-href /$webSiteName/ | %{$_ -replace "\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]"," "} | %{$_ -replace "     ", "`n"}
Write-Host $executionRes
```

This will strip all colors and keep the original text intact, except from some extra whitespace here and there.